# Special character handling in ANTLR lexer

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I wrote the following grammar for string variable declaration. Strings are defined like anything between single quotes, but there must be a way to add a single quote to the string value by escaping using **$** letter.

```
grammar test;

options       
{   
    language = Java;
}


tokens
{   
    VAR = 'VAR';
    END_VAR = 'END_VAR';
}


var_declaration: VAR string_type_declaration END_VAR EOF;

string_type_declaration: identifier ':=' string;

identifier: ID;

string: STRING_VALUE;

STRING_VALUE: '\'' ('$\''|.)* '\'';

ID:  LETTER+;

WSFULL:(' ') {$channel=HIDDEN;};

fragment LETTER: (('a'..'z') | ('A'..'Z'));
```

This grammar doesn't work, if you try to run this code for var_declaration rule:

```
VAR A :='$12.2' END_VAR
```

I get MismatchedTokenException.

But this code works fine for string_type_declaration rule:

```
A :='$12.2'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `STRING_VALUE` isn't properly tokenized. Inside the loop `( ... )*`, the `$` expects a single quote after it, but the string in your input, `'$12.2'`, doesn't have a quote after `$`. You should make the single quote optional `('$' '\''? | .)*`. But now your alternative in the loop, the `.`, will also match a single quote: better let it match anything other than a single quote and `$`:

```
STRING_VALUE
 : '\'' ( '$' '\''? | ~('$' | '\'') )* '\''
 ;
```

resulting in the following parse tree:

[image]